# WIX: files are not copied during REINSTALL

Tags: wix

I run an minor upgrade:

```
msiexec /i Client_v1.1.0.0.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=amus /l*v instal.log
```

But my files aren't copied. In log file I see records:

```
Component: cmpA2E485FCAC32DF9E8B1D2D9D4BD99D25; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
```

Maybe this is the reason why my files aren't copied?
What should I do for my files to be copied during the minor upgrade?
P.S.: I tried to use diferrent REINSTALLMODEs (vomus, vemus, omus, etc.) but no result!

install.log file: https://www.scribd.com/document/321653654/Install

I changed product code, but files aren't copied: install.log file: https://www.scribd.com/document/321859965/Install-2

Comment: Probably best to post the entire verbose log somewhere for us to see.

Comment: install.log file: https://www.scribd.com/document/321653654/Install

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that a minor upgrade requires the new package to have the same ProductCode as the installed one being upgraded, but the ProductCode for your minor upgrade package is new. You're effectively doing a minor upgrade of a product that is not installed, therefore nothing gets "updated". As it says in the log:

MSI (s) (BC:94) [09:04:16:556]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install

Note that the minor upgrade cannot break component rules or it will go into what is called advertised mode and nothing will be updated. Your latest log contains these lines indicating that you have removed a component, so your minor upgrade will fail:

MSI (c) (64:48) [09:27:12:427]: SELMGR: ComponentId '{90370418-9FE8-41E1-916B-0A687E6BD27B}' is registered to feature 'ProductFeature', but is not present in the Component table. Removal of components from a feature is not supported!

MSI (c) (64:48) [09:27:12:427]: SELMGR: Removal of a component from a feature is not supported

Comment: Thanks, that's it. But after installing the minor update, when I try to delete it: all files installed before the update aren't removed. How to deal with this?

Comment: You may have to ask a more detailed precise question.  "..try to delete it.." is not clear as to what "it" is or exactly which product is being deleted (or do you mean uninstall?)

Comment: I mean uninstall from Add/Remove programs. I tried it

Comment: I changed product code, but files aren't copied: install.log file: https://www.scribd.com/document/321859965/Install-2

Answer (score 0):

Please check following details in the log:
(Product registered: entering maintenance mode) if you find this then your minor upgrade is in progress.
Now when you add files new components must have been added, to check whether installation of new components is getting triggered check: 'Request: Local'.
For feature and components, for feature you will find :
(Feature: ABC; Installed: Local;   Request: Reinstall;   Action: Reinstall)
if this feature is getting updated/reinstalled and for components you will find
(Component: DEF; Installed: Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null)
(Component: XYZ; Installed: Local;   Request: Local;   Action: Local)
If all features and components have request field null there is a issue with patch created.

Comment: I used the same id for components and new ids, but files aren't copied

Comment: Please search for [Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallFiles,-----)], under this you will find [Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=CONFIG12.txt,------)], and for each file you will find comments as installer is won't overwrite/overwrite etc depending on versioning rules. Are your files versioned or non versioned? If versioned make sure the version for latest file is higher. Only newer timestamp won't help for versioned files, the version has to be incremented!

Comment: Dll files have version. And how about text files, html, xml?

Comment: I ran into similar issue some days back and this {https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/08/30/how-windows-installer-handles-file-replacement-logic-for-versioned-and-unversioned-files/} link helped me. Check it out for detailed info. For unversioned files MSIFileHash table is very important {https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370107(v=vs.85).aspx}.Also file overwrite rules won't overwrite data files that have been modified (modify date != creation date) so that may be what's going on. Hashing doesn't matter in that case.